# Erro ao executar "react-native run-android": Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, react-native

Após eu instalar algumas bibliotecas do [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) para um projeto, executei o comando `react-native run-android` no cmd mas ele fecha meu servidor e retorna o erro abaixo. Como posso resolver isso?

```bsh
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  > Unable to delete directory 'C:\UsersRafael\DevPost\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\androidx\arch' after 10 attempts
```

[image: Esse é o erro que aparece]

Comment: Tente apagar a pasta node_modules e rodar npm i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É relativamente comum ocorrerem erros de build do Android após a instalação de alguma biblioteca. Isto ocorre se você modifica algum arquivo dentro do diretório `/android` ou se o React Native realiza o *[link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking)* dessa biblioteca.

Por exemplo, a biblioteca citada ([react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)) possui código nativo, então consequentemente o React Native precisa realizar o *link* para que essa biblioteca possa ser utilizada. Vale ressaltar que a partir da versão v0.60 esse *link* é realizado automaticamente (na maioria dos casos).

Quando este tipo de erro ocorrer, limpe a build do Android com o `gradlew clean`. Este comando fará com que todo o conteúdo do diretório `build` seja apagado (veja a [documentação](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#cleaning_outputs)), que é a tarefa que o `react-native run-android` não conseguiu realizar (ênfase na mensagem de erro `Unable to delete directory ...\build\...`).

Para realizar o `gradlew clean`, basta ir no diretório do `android` e executar o comando:

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

E então tente iniciar o projeto novamente. Isso fará com que o Gradle faça todo o processo de build novamente, sendo um pouco mais demorado.