# Erro ao configurar Admob no React Native

Tags: react-native, admob

Tenho que adicionar algumas linhas de código na pasta /Android em meu projeto do React Native para usar o Admob, quando inicio meu projeto `react-native run-android` ele chega nessa parte e ocorre o erro =>

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

adicionei esse codigo:

```
  @Override
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new RNAdMobPackage(),
    );
  }
```

Neste arquivo:

> \android\app\src\main\java\com\novo\MainApplication.java

Arquivo MainApplication.java completo:

```
package com.novo;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.sbugert.rnadmob.RNAdMobPackage;
import com.reactnativecommunity.asyncstorage.AsyncStoragePackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
import com.sbugert.rnadmob.RNAdMobPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {


  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {

          @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

    // CODIGO ADICIONADO AQUI 
    @Override
      protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new RNAdMobPackage(),
        );
      }

 
  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.novo.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

O erro que estou recebendo:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
131 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 129 up-to-date
E:\PROJETOS\novo\android\app\src\main\java\com\novo\MainApplication.java:27: error: illegal start of expression
    );
    ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
E:\PROJETOS\novo\android\app\src\main\java\com\novo\MainApplication.java:27: error: illegal start of expression
```

Basicamente o erro é esse mas não consigo resolver:

```
E:\PROJETOS\novo\android\app\src\main\java\com\novo\MainApplication.java:27: error: illegal start of expression
    );
    ^
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está adicionando a dependência do jeito errado. Veja que já existe um `getPackages` para isso e com comentários indicando como fazer:

```java
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
    List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
    // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
    // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
    return packages;
}
```

Ou seja, antes do `return` basta colocar:

```java
packages.add(new RNAdMobPackage());
```

E apagar o código que você adicionou.

Depois não esqueça de usar o `./gradlew clean` no diretório `/android` para limpar a build, falo disso com mais detalhes [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/481210/100416).